# Add button to java code in Android / Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is it possible to automatically add buttons and lists to the java code from the fragment layout in Eclipse?

I am thinking like it's done in C# / Visual studio where you just assign a name to the listener and the rest is added automatically in the code.

I know how to do it manually. But it's just slightly cumbersome if you have many controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, but you could assing the same method to all the `Views`, for example `android:onClick="handleClick"` and then in your code you need to declare a method like this:

```
public void handleClick(View target){
    switch(target.getId()){
    case R.id.View1:
        /// handle Click on View1
        break;
    case R.id.View2:
        // Handle click on view2
        break;
    /// ,......
    }
}
```

And so you only need one method, and then handle the click event by adding a `case` to the `switch`